# How can i make a templated constructor allowing all of l-value ref, r-value ref and initializer_list?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c++11, rvalue-reference, perfect-forwarding

I'm trying to design a class which has two vectors of large sequences.

```
std::vector<double> factory() {
    return std::vector<double>{1,2,3}; // it actually generates a large sequence of double
}

struct my_class {
    my_class(const std::vector<double>& x, const std::vector<double>& y)
     : m_x(x), m_y(y)
    { }

    std::vector<double> m_x;
    std::vector<double> m_y;
};

int main() {
    my_class c(factory(), factory());
    my_class c2(factory(), {0.5, 1, 1.5});
}
```

Well, it works well but it doesn't use the move constructor of vector. So i tried to change the constructor to accept r-value references with perfect forwarding.

```
struct my_class {
    template<typename X, typename Y>
    my_class(X&& x, Y&& y
             , typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<X, std::vector<double> >::value &&
                                       std::is_convertible<Y, std::vector<double> >::value>::type * = 0
            )
     : m_x(std::forward<X>(x)), m_y(std::forward<Y>(y))
    { }

    std::vector<double> m_x;
    std::vector<double> m_y;
};
```

And now i got a problem. When i try to construct an instance with an initializer_list, i got an error like this.

```
$ g++ -W -Wall -std=gnu++0x a.cpp
a.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
a.cpp:34:32: error: no matching function for call to ‘my_class::my_class(std::vector<double>, <brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
a.cpp:17:18: note: candidate is: my_class::my_class(const my_class&)
```

I thought that `std::initializer_list<double>` might not be convertible to `std::vector<double>`, but it actually is convertible and i got the same error when i tried without the enable_if argument. Am I missing something?

Comment: Out of curiosity which version of g++ are you using? IIRC the `initializer_list` support was incomplete in several recent versions.

Comment: @awoodland I'm using gcc 4.6.2. What do you mean for 'imcomplete'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The preferred idiom is to [pass by value](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/) and then manually move inside the member initializer list:

```
struct my_class {
    my_class(std::vector<double> x, std::vector<double> y)
     : m_x(std::move(x)), m_y(std::move(y))
    { }

    std::vector<double> m_x;
    std::vector<double> m_y;
};
```

This will work with all possible arguments and be reasonably fast:

- If you pass a vector *lvalue*, the vector will be *copied* into `x` and then moved into `m_x`.
- If you pass a vector *rvalue*, the vector will be *moved* into `x` and then moved again into `m_x`.
- If you pass an initializer list, `x` will be initialized from that list and then moved into `m_x`.

The alternative is perfect forwarding, but that makes it harder for the client to know what he may pass in:

```
struct my_class {
    template<typename T, typename U>
    my_class(T&& x, U&& y)
     : m_x(std::forward<T>(x)), m_y(std::forward<U>(y))
    { }

    std::vector<double> m_x;
    std::vector<double> m_y;
};
```

Also, I get a bunch of warnings in g++, so I wouldn't recommend it. Just mentioning it for completeness.

Comment: Pass-by-value will generate a copy of the arguments, which is precisely what user1030861 wants to avoid, if I understand the question corretly.

Comment: @Gabriel: It depends on the value category of the argument. If the argument is an rvalue, call by value will *move* the argument, not copy. A copy is only done if the argument is an lvalue.

Comment: @Gabrial: Updated my answer with a more thorough explanation. Does that help?

Comment: Your second example code doesn't generate any warnings if compiled as `g++ -Wall -std=c++0x` (g++ version 4.5.2).

Comment: @Tony: The warnings appear as soon as you instantiate the constructor template with an initializer list, e.g. `my_class foo({1.0, 2.0, 3.0}, {4.0, 5.0, 6.0});`

Comment: @user: I don't know. It's kinda hard to miss because it's the only answer so far ;)

Comment: @FredOverflow I was not familiar enough with move semantics to realize that passing an rvalue by value would move-construct the rvalue into the actual parameter (or however this should be phrased). Thanks for the explanation!